# Git Push worked, but files are not on server

Tags: git, ssh, push, git-push

I have a git set up on my HostGator shared acct, and I just made my first push. However when I look on the server the files are not there -- Push threw no errors or said anything would be wrong.

I am using an SSH type connection if that makes any difference. And I followed [this guide](http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/) to set up a git repo. The remote origin URL is correct as far as I can tell.

Local LS:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cyclesafestl [master] $ ls

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cyclesafestl
total 32
-rw-r--r--@ 1 503  80    81 Jun 19 10:49 BETA.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 503  80  1772 Jun 18 23:11 index.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 503  80   616 Jun 18 22:49 info.txt
drwxr-xr-x  7 503  80   238 Jun 17 22:59 includes/
-rw-r--r--  1 503  80    76 Jun 17 16:18 README.md
```

Server LS:

```
./
../
HEAD
branches/
config
description
hooks/
info/
objects/
refs/
```

Git Push Info:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cyclesafestl [master] $ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 45, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
Writing objects: 100% (45/45), 498.12 KiB, done.
Total 45 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://xxx@thehivestl.com:xxx/home2/xxx/public_html/thehivestl.com/cyclesafestl
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files are there, you just don't see them because they are embedded into the Git database. This is the difference between initializing a repository with `--bare` or without (see [git-init man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-init) and [this page](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)). On the server side you only see the content of your usual `.git` folder where you should see your project. Try to clone again the same repository in another directory, if you can retrieve your modifications then your setup is just working fine.

Comment: Good point! I tried cloning and the files were there, however I was hoping to use this as sort of a staging platform on my server, so I can push and test and push and test with all my mysql databases in place. BUT when I goto the relative URL I cannot view the page. Should i recreate the page with git init and drop the --bare?

Comment: I would suggest keeping things separate. This repository is here for backup. If you want to setup a staging platform a better solution would be to clone the repository on another directory and use git hooks for instance so that it stays up to date.

Comment: So I could clone this repo on my server in a staging directory and how would git hooks help? Could I set up a hook that notices when files are pushed and keep them up to date in the staging directory?

Comment: A trivial solution would be to set your post-receive hook (see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to something like "cd $staging-dir && git pull origin master"

Comment: I would add that to the config of my staging repo, correct? -- Also, and I can file another question for this, but when I am in my server trying to clone I get a time out issue? tbremer@tbremer.com [~/public_html/thehivestl.com/staging.cyclesafestl]# git clone -v ssh://xxx@thehivestl.com:xxx/home2/xxx/public_html/thehivestl.com/cyclesafestl.git
Cloning into 'cyclesafestl'...
ssh: connect to host thehivestl.com port xxx: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: I figured out my issue above, the relative path was wrong.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you please, give a descriptive solution of how to get the files to show up. The explanation makes sense but does not give a way out for me.

Answer (score 0):

After you complete the push. Run one of the below commands on the remote server,

```
git reset --hard
```

or

```
git stash
```